# Are right continuous functions continuous with the lower limit topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be right continuous. Is $f$ continuous as a function from $\Bbb R$ with the lower limit topology to $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology? It clearly seems like it will be, but I'm not sure how to show it.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $f$ is right continuous at $p$. This means (by my definition) that for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ with $p < x < p + \delta$ we have that $|f(x) - f(p)| < \varepsilon$.

This implies, in set theory terms, that $f[[p,p+\delta)] \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(f(p))$, or: for every open basic neighbourhood $U$ of $f(p)$ we have a basic open neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ (in the lower limit topology) such that $f[V] \subseteq U$. So $f: (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_l) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_e)$ from the lower limit topology to the Euclidean topology is continuous at $p$.

Comment: how does right continuity imply $f([p,p+\delta)) \subset B_\epsilon(f(p))$?